# Prevent Stanford CoreNLP from Americanizing input

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I noticed that the Stanford CoreNLP is Americanizing input which is breaking some of my code since the character offsets don't add up anymore.

I am using the following code:

```
String annotators = "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators",annotators);
this.pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
this.annotators = annotators;
Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
pipeline.annotate(document);
pipeline.prettyPrint(document, resp.getWriter());
```

With the following input:

```
But, at the other end of the town, in his own little hut, there dwelt an honourable laborer.
```

I get:

```
[...]
[Text=an CharacterOffsetBegin=70 CharacterOffsetEnd=72 PartOfSpeech=DT]    
[Text=honorable CharacterOffsetBegin=73 CharacterOffsetEnd=83 PartOfSpeech=JJ] 
[Text=laborer CharacterOffsetBegin=84 CharacterOffsetEnd=91 PartOfSpeech=NN]
[...]
(NP (DT an) (JJ honorable) (NN laborer))
[...]
```

Notice that the input had the word `honourable` but the output has the word `honorable`. Same thing happens with words like `colour` or `harbours`.

Is there a way to prevent that behavior? I don't mind it in the lemmas but I'd like to get the original words so offsets matched.

Comment: Use the option `americanize=false`, as specified in this page: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code for CoreNLP, you want to add the property:

```
props.put("tokenize.options", "americanize=false");
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using `props.put("options"` instead of `props.put("tokenize.options"`